# Create JSON format from two strings in PERL

Tags: json, perl

I've two string like follows in PERL script.

```
$labels = "firstname|lastname|email";

$values = 'krishna|mohan|some@gmail.com';
```

Now I would like to construct a JSON fromat from those two srings. I need to split (explode) both the strings base on `|` (pipe) symbol and construct a JSON format like follows

```
{"firstname":"krishna","lastname":"mohan","email":"krishna@gmail.com"}
```

How can I achieve this? Any Ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: `@j{ split /\|/, $labels } = split /\|/, $values;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split` to "explode" the strings, build a hash from the results. Then, use [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) to translate it to JSON:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON;

my $labels = 'firstname|lastname|email';
my $values = 'krishna|mohan|some@gmail.com'; # Doesn't work with double quotes!

my %hash;
@hash{ split /\|/, $labels } = split /\|/, $values;

print to_json(\%hash);
```